# How to pull variable output from add_action() with do_action() or is there another method?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables

May look a very basic thing to the majority here but i'm stuck.
Here is the PHP code that is in my WP functions file (functions.php):

```
add_action( 'AHEE_event_details_after_the_content', 'my_event_registration_count' );
function my_event_registration_count( $post ) {
  $event_obj = $post->EE_Event;
  $html = '';
  if ( $event_obj instanceof EE_Event ){
    $reg_count = EEM_Event::instance()->count_related(
      $event_obj, 
      'Registration',
      array( 
        array(
          'STS_ID' => array(
            'NOT_IN',
            array(
              EEM_Registration::status_id_cancelled
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
    $html .= '<strong>';
    $html .= $reg_count;
    $html .= ' of ';
    $html .= $event_obj->total_available_spaces();
    $html .= ' attendees total</strong>';
  }
  echo $html;
}
```

I'm trying to get $html output with:

```
<?php do_action( 'my_event_registration_count', $html ); ?>
```

Supposed to give me number of registered event attendees. I need to get this number to my WP front page. Nothing.. Also tried with $reg_count. Is this ting supposed to be global? I'm thankful for all the help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write functions with an output in WordPress is with `add_filter` / `apply_filters`. It's otherwise the same as `add_action` / `do_action`.

Reference:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

Comment: Thank you. Tried,  but still doesn't give me output.

Comment: Can you modify the code in the question with what you did? It should work if done correctly.